# Getting list of filenames from web server using PHP and HTTP request

Tags: java, php, android

First of all I’m new to programming in android (java) and especially in using php, so don’t shoot me if this is a stupid question.

So I’m currently writing an app and in the app it is possible to  upload and delete files  on a ( in the code defined) web server. I already achieved to upload the files using a http request and php. 
I also want to show the files that are on the server in a textView. 
And here my problem occurs. I already searched for days on the internet but I don’t manage to implement this in a correct way into my app.

This is my current java code:

```
   public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    titel = findViewById(R.id.titel);
    text = findViewById(R.id.text);
    maak = findViewById(R.id.button);

}

public void button(View view) {
    new SendRequest().execute();

}

public class SendRequest extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

    protected void onPreExecute() {
    }

    protected String doInBackground(String... arg0) {

        try {

            link = "https://....../~irvdwall/get.php";

            URL url = new URL(link);

            JSONObject postDataParams = new JSONObject();


            HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            conn.setReadTimeout(15000 /* milliseconds */);
            conn.setConnectTimeout(15000 /* milliseconds */);
            conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
            conn.setDoInput(true);
            conn.setDoOutput(true);

            OutputStream os = conn.getOutputStream();
            BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(
                    new OutputStreamWriter(os, "UTF-8"));
            writer.write(getPostDataString(postDataParams));

            writer.flush();
            writer.close();
            os.close();



            int responseCode = conn.getResponseCode();

            if (responseCode == HttpsURLConnection.HTTP_OK) {

                BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream()));
                StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer("");
                String line = "";

                while ((line = in.readLine()) != null) {

                    sb.append(line);
                    break;
                }

                in.close();
                return sb.toString();

            } else {
                return new String("false : " + responseCode);
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            return new String("Exception: " + e.getMessage());
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
    /*Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), result,
            Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();*/
        text.setText(result);
    }

    public String getPostDataString(JSONObject params) throws Exception {

        StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
        boolean first = true;

        Iterator<String> itr = params.keys();

        while(itr.hasNext()){

            String key = itr.next();
            Object value = params.get(key);

            if (first)
                first = false;
            else
                result.append("&");

            result.append(URLEncoder.encode(key, "UTF-8"));
            result.append("=");
            result.append(URLEncoder.encode(value.toString(), "UTF-8"));

        }
        return result.toString();
    }
}
```

This is my php code (get.php):

```
 <?php
$dir = "https://.../~irvdwall/";  // here comes the full http-address to the folder where all the files are located (index) 
$b = scandir($dir,1); 
echo implode(" ",$b);
```

So what’s wrong with this code, is it my php code?
And how can I change it to create a working thing?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: `// here comes the full http-address to the folder where all the files are located (index) 
$b = scandir($dir,1); ` Why a full https address? You only need a relative directory path. Relative to your php script. ''$dir=".";`could be used. Try "." and tell which echo text you receive in your Android app.

Comment: `sb.append(line);
                    break;` That should be `sb.append(line + "\n");`. Remove that `break;`.

Comment: `writer.close();
            os.close();` Think you have to remove both.

Comment: Oh wow thank you. It finally works. It was indeed the relative path that I needed instead of the full adress. It seems also logic that the break has to be removed now you are mentioning it. But I always thought you had to close a writer or reader at the end to make a code according the 'rules of the art'.  (even though it also works when you remove it.)

Comment: Your post data string is empty. So you did write nothing.